# Can a Grunt task be configured to run a single Karma test?

Tags: gruntjs, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

When developing a test I would like to be able to run a single Karma unit test only. Is there a way to run one test only from the command line using Karma, or perhaps configure a simple task in Grunt that runs one test only?

Answer (score 9):

Assuming that you're using Karma with Jasmine, simply change one or more `describe()` calls to `fdescribe()` calls, or `it()` calls to `fit()` calls. Only the `f`-prefixed tests will be run. This is documented in the [`focused_specs.js`](http://jasmine.github.io/2.1/focused_specs.html) file of the Jasmine documentation.

(In older versions of Jasmine, the 'focused' versions of `describe` and `it` were instead called `ddescribe` and `iit`; try them if you're on an old version and can't upgrade.)

Comment: I recommend using grunt ddescribe-iit plugin for preventing you from accidentally comitting a ddescribe or iit into your project. See project's Github page - https://github.com/btford/grunt-ddescribe-iit